# I have a list of skewed menu, how can I align it well?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, its a bootstrap menu with a little bit customized that has a skewed menu you noticed that when I inspect element it, the first menu on the left is overflowed on the width of the container and last menu does not meet on the end of the container, what is the best solution to align it in both sides? Thanks

[image: .]

```css
.nav-tabs {
  border: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-family: 'Klavika Bd';
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 28px;
    border: 0;


}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  margin: 0;
   border-radius: 0;
   font-family: 'Klavika Bd';
   text-decoration: none;
   font-size: 28px;
   color: #fff;
   border:0;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 58px;

}


.nav-tabs > li {
  width: 32.1%;
  margin-right: 1.2%;
}


.nav-tabs > li > a:before {
     content: '';
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: #ff4600;
     transform: skew(-10deg);
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: -1;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a:hover:before {
  background: #ff6c34;
}

.nav-tabs > li.active > a:before {
  background: #d1d2d4;
}


.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs>li {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#top10" aria-controls="top10" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">1. PICK YOUR TOP 10</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#review" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">2. REVIEW</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#submit" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">3. SUBMIT & SHARE</a></li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

The main culprit of why the left side is padded different then the right is your `li` rule:

```
.nav-tabs > li {
  width: 32.1%;
  margin-right: 1.2%;
}
```

With this rule, the first one has no margin on the left and all others have margin on both sides.  The easiest way to get this aligned evenly is to change it to:

```
.nav-tabs > li {
  width: 32.1%;
  margin-right: .6%;
  margin-left: .6%;
}
```

Alternatively you could apply a rule specifically to either the first or last `li` using `li:first-child` or `li:last-child` to adjust as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to add a bit of `margin-left` to `.nav-tabs>li`:

```
.nav-tabs>li {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

How much margin you add depends on how much offset you need.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This one is good too but, I will explore another test for this one thank you.